# Determine whether the following graphs are isomorphic or not

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

> Determine whether the following graphs are isomorphic or not.
>   [image]
>   $\qquad\qquad(a)\text{ Petersen graph}\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad(b)$

First I check degrees of those two graph and unfortunately they are same. Then I tried to find any geometrical shape$(\text{graph invariants})$ which wasn't in other. And I think there is no hexagon shape can possible in figure $1$. Is it enough to said that they are not isomorphic or I have missing something$?$

The graph isomorphism problem is one of few standard problems in computational complexity theory belonging to NP. **But are there any special things to check to determine whether two graphs are isomorphic or not. Is there a step by step checklist to check?**

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.
**Edited**: I update my sketch now it look alike Petersen Graph

Comment: Is (a) meant to be the Petersen graph?

Comment: Yes @LordSharktheUnknown maybe my drawing is confusing let me mention that in body. thanks

Comment: Cycles are preserved by isomorphisms. If you find that one has a cycles of length $6$ and the other doesn't, then they are not isomorphic.

Comment: The graphs **are** isomorphic.  ABCDIFA is a cycle of length 6 in the standard Petersen graph.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

As the above labeling shows, the two graphs are isomorphic.  Once you have it in your mind that it's possible, it's simple to do.  Just pick a 5-cycle, label those vertices A through E, and then the remaining vertex adjacent to A not on that cycle has to be F and so on to the end.

A bunch of years ago, I wrote a proof that there was only one graph up to isomorphism (i.e. the Petersen graph) on ten vertices that was 3-regular and had a diameter of 2.  I can post that as well if you are interested.

Comment: Your labeling has f adjacent to i, which isn't the case. I don't believe they are isomorphic, see my answer.

Comment: @MichaelBiro He clarified in comments that the graph on the left is intended to be the Petersen graph, so f is adjacent to i.

Comment: Ok, then the figure needs to be changed. It currently is definitely not the Petersen graph.

Comment: @MatthewDaly It look like you assume that the two graphs are isomorphic before labeling. But I am always get confusion to check that. Besides, your $5$-cycle choice made it easily to labeling but I am afraid I wasn't enough confident to pick such better thing in general. Could you give me some guideline. Thanks again for your answer(+1)

Comment: @NajmunNahar Actually, the Petersen graph is vertex-transitive, which means that you could pick any 5-cycle at all and it would work just as well.  Anyways, you have to take a side one way or the other to solve a problem, just like you were assuming that the graphs were not isomorphic when you looked for an invariant that they didn't have in common.

Answer (score 4):

This is a well-known exercise and appears in at least one text in combinatorial analysis.

To prove isomorphism, it suffices to find a vertex labeling of each graph such that the corresponding adjacency matrices are identical.  This furnishes an explicit edge-preserving bijection.

Using the labeling in your figure, and using lexicographical ordering for the Petersen graph as the row/column order for the resulting adjacency matrix, we have $$\begin{array}{c|cccccccccc} & a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h & i & j \\
\hline
a & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
b & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
c & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
d & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
e & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
f & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
g & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
h & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
i & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
j & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0
\end{array}$$

Now all we need to do is identify $\{q, \ldots, z\}$ with $\{a, \ldots, j\}$ so that the resulting adjacency matrix is the same.  There clearly is more than one such mapping, so suppose $$\{q, r, w, v\} \to \{a, b, f, e\}.$$  Then since $\{q, r, y, z, w\}$ is a $5$-cycle, it needs to map to a $5$-cycle of the form $\{a, b, ?, ?, f\}$ in the Petersen graph.  This forces the choice $y \to c$ and $z \to h$.  Similarly, $\{q, v, x, z, w\}$ is another $5$-cycle which must map to $\{a, e, ?, h, f\}$ and the only candidate is $x \to j$.  This identifies $7$ of the $10$ vertices and the remaining $3$ are again forced after considering the remaining labels adjacent to $b$ and $e$:  $$\{s, t, u\} \to \{g, i, d\}.$$  Thus we have the candidate bijection $$\{q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z\} \leftrightarrow \{a, b, g, i, d, e, f, j, c, h\}$$ or equivalently $$\{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j\} \leftrightarrow \{q, r, y, u, v, w, s, z, t, x\}.$$  Now construct the adjacency matrix for the second graph with this ordering of vertices, and compare the result.

Comment: nice explanation(+1) @heropup thanks